# 503 DNS resolution failed for gemini pro fine-tuning

Tags: http-status-code-503, google-cloud-dns, fine-tuning, google-gemini, gemini

```
import os
if 'COLAB_RELEASE_TAG' in os.environ:
  from google.colab import userdata
  import pathlib
  pathlib.Path('client_secret.json').write_text(userdata.get('CLIENT_SECRET'))

  # Use `--no-browser` in colab
  !gcloud auth application-default login --no-browser --client-id-file client_secret2.json --scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/generative-language.tuning'
else:
  !gcloud auth application-default login --client-id-file client_secret2.json --scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/generative-language.tuning'

!pip install -q -U google-generativeai

import google.generativeai as genai

genai.configure(transport='grpc')

for i, m in zip(range(5), genai.list_tuned_models()):
  print(m.name)
```

**I run the above codes one by one on Google's newly released Gemini Pro Fine-Tuning notebook. However, when I run the last code, I constantly get 503 DNS error on the image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6b2o.png). How can I solve this problem?**